# ada split() method

Tags: string, parameters, split, ada

I am trying to write an Ada equivalent to the split() method in Java or C++. I am to intake a string and an integer and output two seperate string values. For example:
split of "hello" and 2 would return:
"The first part is he
and the second part is llo"

The code I have is as follows:

```
-- split.adb splits an input string about a specified position.
--
-- Input: Astring, a string,
--        Pos, an integer.
-- Precondition: pos is in Astring'Range.
-- Output: The substrings Astring(Astring'First..Pos) and
--                        Astring(Pos+1..Astring'Last).
--------------------------------------------------------------

with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Strings.Fixed;
use  Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Strings.Fixed;

procedure Split is

   EMPTY_STRING : String := "                                        ";

   Astring, Part1, Part2 : String := EMPTY_STRING;
   Pos, Chars_Read       : Natural;

   ------------------------------------------------
   -- Split() splits a string in two.           
   -- Receive: The_String, the string to be split,
   --          Position, the split index.        
   -- PRE: 0 < Position <= The_String.length(). 
   --     (Ada arrays are 1-relative by default)
   -- Passback: First_Part - the first substring,
   --           Last_Part - the second substring.
   ------------------------------------------------
   function Split(TheString : in String ; Pos : in Integer; Part1 : out String ; Part2     : out String)  return String is 
   begin
    Move(TheString(TheString'First .. Pos), Part1);
    Move(TheString(Pos .. TheString'Last), Part2);
    return Part1, Part2;
     end Split;



begin                                           -- Prompt for input
   Put("To split a string, enter the string: ");
   Get_Line(Astring, Chars_Read);
   Put("Enter the split position: ");
   Get(Pos);

   Split(Astring, Pos, Part1, Part2);

   Put("The first part is ");
   Put_Line(Part1);
   Put(" and the second part is ");
   Put_Line(Part2);

end Split;
```

The main part I am having trouble with is returning the two separate string values and in general the whole split() function. Any pointers or help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: +1 for a (nearly) [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a `function`, consider making `Split` a `procedure` having two `out` parameters, as you've shown. Then decide if `Pos` is the *last* index of `Part1` or the *first* index of `Part2`; I've chosen the latter.

```ada
procedure Split(
   TheString : in String; Pos : in Integer;
   Part1 : out String; Part2 : out String) is 
begin
   Move(TheString(TheString'First .. Pos - 1), Part1);
   Move(TheString(Pos .. TheString'Last), Part2);
end Split;
```

Note that `String` indexes are `Positive`:

```ada
type String is array(Positive range <>) of Character;
subtype Positive is Integer range 1 .. Integer'Last;
```

Comment: I can see how that would work. With this though, I am getting a "raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : split.adb:38 range check failed" error when running the program

Comment: figured it out! Thank you for this :)

Comment: I have a couple of issues with this: The output strings aren't really strings, but Ada `String` buffers. In order to use them, the client has to do some extra math to figure out the length of valid data in them. Also, the client has to do some math up-front to make sure both buffers are large enough. The first problem can be fixed with two more out parameters for the lengths and a couple more lines of code. The second requires using Ada.Strings.Unbounded instead.

Comment: Updated based on rejected [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1586138).

Answer (score 4):

Doing this is so trivial, I'm not sure why you'd bother making a routine for it. Just about any routine you could come up with is going to be much harder to use anyway.

```
Front_Half : constant String := Original(Original'first..Index);
Back_Half  : constant String := Original(Index+1..Original'last);
```

Done.

Note that static Ada strings are *very* different than strings in other languages like C or Java. Due to their static nature, they are best built either inline like I've done above, or as return values from functions. Since functions cannot return more than one value, a single unified "split" routine is just plain not a good fit for static Ada string handling. Instead, you should either do what I did above, call the corresponding routines from Ada.Strings.Fixed (`Head` and `Tail`), or switch to using `Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String` instead of `String`.

The latter is probably the easiest option, if you want to keep your Java mindset about string handling. If you want to really learn Ada though, I'd highly suggest you learn to deal with static fixed `String`s the Ada way.

Comment: I agree with your [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971565/230513), and +1 to you, Marc & Brian. I think all three answers highlight a virtue of doing this exercise in Ada as a way to study different ways to model strings. Most other languages only have one.

Comment: +1 for constant. My only beef with doing this (and I do it a lot) is that it gets messy writing a parser this way! I am trying to train myself to abstract over `Original(Index+1..Original'last)` with simple functions as in my answer, in an attempt to clarify the intent.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Ahhh. Well, if you are writing a *parser*, then I'd suggest a few possible changes: 1. Use a common `String` buffer (with of course a separate length variable) and just pass indices around. Don't bother copying data out of the buffer until you really need to. 2. Don't use Ada.Strings.Unbounded. Ada.Strings.**Bounded** may work for you, but really just see point 1. 3. You may consider looking at [OpenToken](http://www.stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html), which can do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: @T.E.D. Good points all : for small parsing tasks, OpenToken is probably overkill; agreed that manipulating indices is better than manipulating strings!

Answer (score 3):

From looking over your code you *really* need to read up in general on the [String type](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Strings), because you're dragging in a lot of expectations in from other languages on how to work with them--which aren't going to work with them. Ada's String type is not one of its more flexible features, in that they are *always* fixed length. While there are ways of working around the limitations in a situation such as you're describing, it would be much easier to simply use [Unbounded_Strings](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html).

The input String to your function could remain of type String, which will adjust to the length of the string that you provide to it. The two output Unbounded_Strings then are simply set to the sliced string components after invoking To_Unbounded_String() on each of them.

Comment: I do know that about the different types of string in Ada! For sake of the assignment, howevever, I am to stay with just type String for simplicity.

Comment: @user1998581 - If you want simplicity, use Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String instead. You'll find those work much more like the Java strings (I'm guessing) you are used to. Handling static Ada strings requires a whole different mindset (and a `split` routine ain't part of it).

Comment: @user1998581: Marc, Brian & T.E.D. offer cogent, practical advice. While `String` itself is a bit primitive, the standard Ada library offers a variety of string models with different trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints of your main program, with all strings bounded by the size of EMPTY_STRING. the procedure with out parameters is the correct approach, with the out parameter storage allocated by the caller (on the stack as it happens)

That is not always the case, so it is worth knowing another way. The problem is how to deal with data whose size is unknown until runtime.

Some languages can only offer runtime allocation on the heap (via "new" or "malloc") and can only access the data via pointers, leaving a variety of messy problems including accesses off the end of the data (buffer overruns) or releasing the storage correctly (memory leaks, accessing freed pointers etc)

Ada will allow this method too, but it is usually unnecessary and strongly discouraged. Unbounded_String is a wrapper over this method, while Bounded_String avoids heap allocation where you can accept an upper bound on the string length.

But also, Ada allows variable sized data structures to be created on the stack; the technique just involves creating a new stack frame and declaring new variables where you need to, with "declare". The new variables can be initialised with function calls.

Each function can only return one object, but that object's size can be determined at runtime. So either "Split" can be implemented as 2 functions, returning Part1 or Part2, or it can return a record containing both strings. It would be a record with two size discriminants, so I have chosen the simpler option here. The function results are usually built in place (avoids copying).

The flow in your example would require two nested Declare blocks; if "Pos" could be identified first, they could be collapsed into one...

```ada
procedure Split is

   function StringBefore( Input : String; Pos : Natural) return String is
   begin
      return Input(1 .. Pos-1);
   end StringBefore;

   function StringFrom ...

begin                                           
   Put("To split a string, enter the string: ");
   declare
      AString : String := Get_Line;
      Pos     : Natural;
   begin
      Put("Enter the split position: ");
      Get(Pos);
      declare 
         Part1 : String := StringBefore(AString, Pos);
         Part2 : String := StringFrom(AString, Pos);
      begin
         Put("The first part is ");
         Put_Line(Part1);
         Put(" and the second part is ");
         Put_Line(Part2);
      end;   -- Part1 and Part2 are now out of scope
   end;      -- AString is now out of scope
end Split;
```

This can obviously be wrapped in a loop, with different size strings each time, with no memory management issues.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Head and Tail functions in Ada.Strings.Fixed.

`function Head (Source : in String; Count : in Natural; Pad : in Character := Space) return String;`

`function Tail (Source : in String; Count : in Natural; Pad : in Character := Space)
return String;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that just uses slices of the string.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed;
procedure Main is
   str : String := "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight";
   pattern : String := ",";
   idx, b_idx : Integer;
begin
   b_idx := 1;
   for i in 1..Ada.Strings.Fixed.Count ( Source => str, Pattern => pattern ) loop
      idx := Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index( Source => str(b_idx..str'Last), Pattern => pattern);
      Put_Line(str(b_idx..idx-1)); -- process string slice in any way
      b_idx := idx + pattern'Length;
   end loop;
   -- process last string
   Put_Line(str(b_idx..str'Last)); 
end Main;
```