# Ada - How do you read an array from a single line of input?

Tags: ada

My question is pretty simple, I have input that looks like this...

```
0   0   0   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   1
```

And I need to store these values into an array but I can't figure it out. This is what I have so far...

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    type arr is array(1..10) of Integer;
    Data : arr;
begin
    for I in 1..arr'Length loop
        Data(I) := Integer'Value(Get_Line);
    end loop;
end Main;
```

I know this wrong and it's pretty obvious why this isn't working. I'm trying to store multiple values into a single integer, I need a way to iterate over the input or load all the values at once. How would you do this in Ada?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970642/ada-split-method

Comment: This is really the easiest way to do it? I feel like what I'm doing shouldn't be this complicated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Get_Line to get the whole line as a string and then Ada.Integer_Text_IO to parse the string:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Hello is
    Line : String := Get_Line;
    Value : Integer;
    Last : Positive := 1;
begin

    while Last < Line'Last loop
        Get(Line(Last..Line'Last),Value,Last);
        Put_Line(Value'Image);  -- Save the value to an array here instead
        Last := Last + 1;    -- Needed to move to the next part of the string
    end loop;

end Hello;
```

After that, you can load the values into an array in the loop or however you like.

Example output:

```
$gnatmake -o hello *.adb
gcc -c hello.adb
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatlink hello.ali -o hello
$hello
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
-1
-1
-1
 1
```

EDIT:  Adding a recursive option that is more general.  This will read a line from STDIN and recursively concatenate the values into an array.  It uses the secondary stack to do so in GNAT.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_Io;

procedure Hello is

    -- Need an array return type
    type Integer_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;

    -- Recursive function
    function Get_Ints return Integer_Array is

        Value : Integer;

    begin
        -- Read from STDIN using Integer_Text_IO;
        Get(Value);

        -- Concatinate recursively
        return Integer_Array'(1 => Value) & Get_Ints;

    exception
        -- I found different exceptions with different versions
        -- of GNAT, so using "others" to cover all versions
        when others => 
            -- Using Ada2012 syntax here.  If not using Ada2012
            -- then just declare the Empty variable somewhere
            -- and then return it here
            return Empty : Integer_Array(1..0);

    end Get_Ints;

    Result : Integer_Array := Get_Ints;

begin
  Put_Line("Hello, world!");
  Put_Line(Integer'Image(Result'Length));
  for E of Result loop
    Put(Integer'Image(E) & " ");
  end loop;
end Hello;
```

Comment: Your updated approach comports with the guidance seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005896/230513). Note that you can handle exceptions selectively, e.g.`when Data_Error | End_Error…` as the need arises.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you have 10 elements to read, it can be done a little more simply like this:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Hello is
   A: array (1..10) of Integer;
begin
   for V of A loop
      Get(V);
   end loop;
   for I in A'Range loop
      Put(I, 5);
      Put(": ");
      Put(A(I), 5);
      New_Line;
   end loop;
end Hello;
```

If you don't actually know how many elements to read in advance, please update the question.

Comment: Yeah my assumption since they were using stdin as part of their question was that the actual input was going to be a random number of integers.  If not, this is the better approach.

Comment: Yup, in my problem the input will always be 10 values, thanks for the help.

Comment: After thinking about it, I came up with an even simpler solution using recursion.  I edited my response above with it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this already was answered, I'd like to add a couple improvements to Jere's answer.

It is more Ada-like to terminate the recursion using End_Of_File rather than an exception. Plus, it makes the program clearer.

Also, using tail-call recursion instead of normal recursion allows the compiler to perform some optimization.

```
function Get_Ints(input : in File_Type) return Integer_Array is
    function Get_Ints_Rec(accumulator : in Integer_Array) return Integer_Array is
        value : Integer;
    begin
        if End_Of_File(input) then
            return accumulator;
        else
            begin
               Get(input, value);
            exception
               when Data_Error => -- problem when reading
                  if not End_Of_Line(input) then
                     Skip_Line(input);
                  end if;
                  return Get_Ints_Rec(acc);
            end;
            return Get_Ints_Rec(accumulator & (1 => value));
        end if;
    end Get_Ints_Rec;

    acc : constant Integer_Array(1 .. 0) := (others => 0);
begin
    return Get_Ints_Rec(acc);
end Get_Ints;
```

Comment: I like it.  I wasn't able to get it working with standard input on my system.  Any suggestions for that?  Quick example:   http://tpcg.io/XgcNzT

Comment: It looks like a problem on the online compiler (or maybe a newline problem like in another recent SO question, I do not know for sure). On your test, I can read a single line with multiple integers just fine, but I have to add `Skip_line(input);` after getting the integer if I want to read multiple lines.Integer_Text_IO _should_ ignore line ends, as stated in [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html) That's very odd, I will look into it further.

Comment: I'm guessing a newline problem as well.  This also failed on a linux system I tried it on.

Comment: After testing left and right, I'm about 100% sure it's a newline problem. The code failed when reading a file with Windows newlines on a Linux Machine. Reading with unix newlines worked as well as reading from stdin on my computer. The code worked on Windows also. I edited the answer to workaround this problem (not very happy with the workaround, though).